# Trouble locating and displaying list of records from a relationship model in Rails app

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a relationship model that tracks customers (users) of shops in a `has_many :through` association.  I'm having trouble with my `ShopsController` and finding the list of relationships for a given shop, then displaying them.

My error is a RecordNotFound, `Couldn't find Relationship with 'id'=` so I'm having issues with how relationships are created and identified.  They need to be found based on a `user_id` when a shop is logged in (`current_shop_id` is then given)  How can I rework this to make relationships/show work?

In the current version a shop has_many users through relationships:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :users, through: :relationships
```

Relationships takes the user's id and shop's id and creates a relationship id:

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "relationships", ["shop_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_shop_id"


  add_index "relationships", ["user_id", "shop_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_user_id_and_shop_id", unique: true
  add_index "relationships", ["user_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_user_id"
```

A user is added in the shop model:

```
  # New relationship
  def add(user)
    relationships.create(user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def remove(user)
    relationships.find_by(user.id).destroy
  end
```

@relationships is defined in the shop controller:

```
def relationships
@title = "Following"
@relationships = Relationship.find(params[:relationship_id])
@users = @shop.relationships.paginate(page: params[:page])
render 'show_relationships'
end
```

and the relationship is created in the relationship controller

```
  def create
    user = User.find(params[user_id: user.id])
    current_shop.add(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
```

Then these relationships should be shown in relationships/show

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if @relationships.any? %>
      <ul class="users follow">
        <%= render @relationships %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `relationships` method in your controller is all over the place.

You're trying to find relationship**S** using a find by id with a non-existent `params[:relationship_id]` which is causing the error you're seeing.

You're then setting `@users` to be all the relationships for the `@shop`.

Then you're rendering a template `show_relationships` but you refer later to a `relationships/show` template.

Additionally in the shop model you're calling `create` on relationships with just a user id whereas you'd expect to be passing in some attributes for the relationship.

It looks like this code has got messier and messier as you've tried to solve the problem. To be perfectly honest I'd go back to the beginning and start again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your use case, a shop has many customers and a customer frequents many shops.

The result of doing this the Rails way is you can retrieve customers belonging to a specific shop just by using an instance of that shop and calling `shop.customers` You can find a specific customer for that shop, by calling `shop.customers.find(:id)` If you try calling for another shops customer, you get a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundError`

Ditto the other way round. To retrieve the shops a customer frequents, ideally you want `customer.shops` etc as above. To add a new shop to a customer, use `customer.shops.create("Arkwrights Dairy")`

As Shadwell stated your current efforts to create the structure are far more complicated than you need. And you do not set this up through the controllers, only through the models.

Models, 2 only

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
```

Migrations, 3

```
class SampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shops do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string  :name
    end

    create_table :customers_shops, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :customer
      t.belongs_to :shop  
    end
  end
end
```

Add more detail to the models as you see fit, but this should be enough to establish the relationships. Things to watch are the plurals, shop verse shops is important. Shop the class and belongs_to :shop are both singular. References to many shops is plural and tables hold many shops so are also plural. And the join table has to be in alphabetical order, customers_shops not shops_customers.

Once set up, run your migrations then try.

```
shop = Shop.create(name: "Dairy")
=> #<Shop id:1, name: "Dairy">
shop.customers.create(name: "Bill")
=> #<Customer id:1, name: "Bill">

customer = Customer.find(1)
=> #<Customer id:1, name: "Bill">
customer.shops
=> [#<Shop id:1, name: "Dairy">]
```

Note that shops returns an array. Access the first element using customer.shops[0] or alternatively customer.shops.find(1) to retrieve the shop using its :id

Hopefully that will give you the foundation you need :-)

Answer (score 0):

> ... for a given shop ...

This suggests that you should be finding an instance of Shop, and from it using associations to retrieve the appropriate Users. I'd expect to see this in a shop-oriented view, not a relationship view, and for there to be an association on Shop of:

```
has_many :users, through => :relationships
```

Comment: That's the current build, I added the relevant part of the shop model above to show that.  Could you show how this is carried through the controllers and user model to make relationships work?