# Having trouble rendering checkboxes in a Rails 4 many_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `many_to_many` association between `Categories` and `Articles`, using `has_and_belongs_to_many` in a Rails 4 app:

Here are the corresponding migration and classes:

```
class CategoriesArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories_articles, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :category, index: true
      t.belongs_to :article, index: true
    end
    add_index :categories_articles, [:category_id, :article_id]
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

When a user creates a new article, I simply want to give him or her the option to select categories that he/she wants to associate with the new article. I want the user to be able to select these categories with checkboxes.

Here's the `ArticlesController`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy, :update]
  before_action :verify_own_article, only: [:destroy]
  respond_to :html

  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @articles = current_user.article_feed
      # TODO: if there are too few articles on a user's feed, we want to display more articles
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
    @articles = @articles.page(params[:page] || 1).per(12)
    respond_with(@articles)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@article)
  end

  def new
    @categories = Category.all
    @article = Article.new
    respond_with(@article)
  end

  def edit
    if current_user.articles.find_by_id(params[:id]).nil?
      flash[:notice] = "You do not have permission to edit this article."
      redirect_to @article
    end
  end

  def create
    # Creates article object with current_user_id, initial_comment, and URL
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

    # Uses Pismo (gem) to grab title, content, photo of URL
    @article.populate_url_fields
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "Article created!"

      # Might need to change the location of this redirect
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid article."
      redirect_to new_article_path
    end

  end

  def update
    @article.update(article_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Article successfully updated."
    respond_with(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    if @article
      @article.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Article successfully destroyed."
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You do not have permission to delete this article."
    end
    # TODO: change this to another redirect location
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:url, :title, :datetime, :content, :photo, :initial_comment)
    end

    # Ensure that a signed in user can only delete articles that they have posted
    def verify_own_article
      @article = current_user.articles.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Here's the article `new.html.erb` view:

```
<h1>New article</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

... and the `form` partial:

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :initial_comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :initial_comment %>
  </div>


  <% @categories.each do |t| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label t.name %>
      <%= f.check_box "categories[#{t.id}]" %>
      <br />
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, this is erroring for me, specifically the lines:

```
<% @categories.each do |t| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label t.name %>
          <%= f.check_box "categories[#{t.id}]" %>
          <br />
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Specifically, it's telling me:

`undefined method 'categories[1]' for #<Article:0x007f401193d520>`. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You're using nested form(http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast). So, read the details.

Answer (score 0):

I note your join table is named

```
create_table :categories_articles, id: false do |t|
```

The name needs to be in alphabetical order.

```
create_table :articles_categories, id: false do |t|
```

My pick is that Rails cannot find your join table. This means that the form when it calls @article.categories cannot find what it needs. The same will happen if you call @category.articles (ie: being able to find the join table is not related to the arbitrary order of the objects).

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283678/trouble-locating-and-displaying-list-of-records-from-a-relationship-model-in-rai/29514378#29514378)